# Does dictionary assignment results in pointing to the same object in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

While implementing some design patterns in Python, I found something interesting about Dictionaries that seems unusual. I created a variable `dict1` with dict constructor. Then `dict1` was assigned to `dict2`. But while changing a value of a key in `dict2`, it affected `dict1`.

Code:

```
dict1 = dict(a=1, b=2)
dict2 = dict1
print("dict1 = ", dict1)
print("dict2 = ", dict2)

# assigning value of key 'a' in dict2 only
dict2['a'] = 0
print("---------------------------")
print("dict1 = ", dict1)
print("dict2 = ", dict2)
```

Output:

```
dict1 =  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
dict2 =  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
---------------------------
dict1 =  {'b': 2, 'a': 0}
dict2 =  {'b': 2, 'a': 0}
```

I found the same type of behavior for Lists also:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1
print(list1, list2)
print("---------------------------")
list2.append(4)
print(list1, list2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
---------------------------
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But not in strings:

```
str1 = "Good"
str2 = str1
print(str1, ",", str2)
print("---------------------------")
str2+=" thing"
print(str1, ",", str2)
```

Output:

```
Good , Good
---------------------------
Good , Good thing
```

It is obvious that dictionary & list assignment differs from string assignment. But how does it work? I was looking for some explanation or related resources. Can anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `differs from string assignment` nope, they don't differ. but strings are immutable, so you can't change them anyway. see the `id` function to see what object are actually the same as others.

Comment: in the case of string, `+=` returns a different string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Python knows names and values.
2. When you do `x = something`, `x` is a new name for the value of `something`.
3. Assignment never copies data.

With that in mind, let's go over the two examples:

When you do

```
dict2 = dict1
```

`dict2` is a new name for the dictionary `{'a':1, 'b':2}` *which also has the name `dict1`*. All changes to the dictionary will be visible across all names!

When you do

```
str2 += " thing"
```

you are **rebinding** the name `str2` to the result of `str2 + " thing"`. You are building an entirely new string, and rebind the name `str2`. `str1` and `str2` are now names for different strings and `str1` is still pointing to the original string.

One last thing/pitfall to keep in mind: sometimes, the `+=` operator can trick you and `x += y` will do something else than `x = x + y`.

Here's an example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = x
>>> x = x + [4, 5, 6]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
```

As expected, when you do `x = x + [4, 5, 6]`, you build a new list and *rebind* the name `x`. `y` is still pointing to the old list. However...

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = x
>>> x += [4, 5, 6]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This is unexpected, since conceptually

```
x += [4, 5, 6]
```

should do the same as

```
x = x + [4, 5, 6]
```

What happens is that when you use `+=` you are calling `__iadd__` on `x`, i.e. what happens is `x.__iadd__([4, 5, 6])`.

In the case of lists, `__iadd__` *extends* the list in place instead of building a new list object, so `x += [4, 5, 6]` was equivalent to

```
x.extend([4, 5, 6])
```

and then returning `x`. Strings behave as expected when using `+=`, i.e. a new string is built and you reassign the name.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question posed in the title is "yes". But this is not specific to dicts and lists - it is exactly the same for any object.

Neither is it true that assignment differs from strings. The only difference is that dicts and lists allow you to mutate them; you can see that your code does different things in each case - append for a list and key assignment for a dict, but += for a string. These are different operations, so it shouldn't surprise you that they have different behaviours.